# Word for Matrix "Scaling"

Tags: matrices, terminology

If $x$, $y$ and $a$ are real-valued numbers and $x=ay$, then we can say "$x$ is a 'scaled' version of $y$" or "$y$ is 'scaled' by $a$ to get $x$." Is there an analogous term for matrices? That is, if $X$, $Y$ and $A$ are matrices and $X=AY$, I'd like to be able to say $X$ is a ___ version of $Y$. Is there any good term to fill in the blank? I feel like there should be a word for this but I'm struggling to come up with it.

Comment: How about "transformed", as in "linear transformation"?

Comment: Transformation was all I could think of as well. I guess qualifying it with "linear" might help at least.